# Strange behaviour in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

folks, I am a mobile developer trying to understand better JQuery. I bought a book plenty of examples. One of them is next code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>jQuery Select Hidden</title>
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

$( document ).ready( function() { 

  var i = 0, str = "Hidden: " ;
  var hid = $( "body" ).find( "*" ).filter( ":hidden" ) ;
  for( ; i < hid.length; i++ )
  { str += ( hid[i].tagName + " | " ) } ;
  $( "#out" ).text( str + hid.length ) ;

} ) ;

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>jQuery</h1>
<div style="display:none"><b>Hidden Text</b></div>
<p>Output: <span id="out"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

It is supposed should be showing a string containing all the hidden elements (DIV and B) this out:

**jQuery**

Output: Hidden: DIV | B | 2

Easy to understand and exactly what is coming out when open in Firefox. But in Chrome the out is this:

**jQuery**
Output: Hidden: DIV | B | SPAN | 3

So, it is considering SPAN tag as a hidden element.
Somebody knows why it is happening?

Screenshot added:

[image]

Comment: I tested your code in Chrome 77, and I got "Output: Hidden: DIV | B | 2"

Comment: Press F12, and examine the structure of the page (Elements tab).

Comment: In jsfiddle I got "Output: Hidden: DIV | B | SCRIPT | 3". The page structure shows a hidden script tag, added by the jsfiddle application.

Comment: I am not using jsfiddle and my Chrome current version: Google Chrome is up to date
Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: Ill bet you $20 one of those chrome extensions is adding a hidden span to the pages. Open it in incognito and see if you get the expected output ;)